# Show that if $\delta (G) \geq (p-1)/2$, then G is connected.

Tags: graph-theory

I found this problem in *Graph Theory* by Ronald Gould; it's problem 22 of Chapter 2. I wanted help with this proof; I think I found the answer to it, but I want someone more experienced to check it.

$\delta(G)$ refers to the minimum degree of any vertex in the graph $G$ and "$p$" refers to the order of $G$, i.e. $p = |V|$.

My proof so far is as follows:
Suppose $\delta(G) \geq (p-1)/2.$

If $G$ is disconnected, then $G$ must have a component $S \subset V$ with the property that $\forall x \in S$, $x$ is adjacent only to other members of $S$.
Since each $x \in S$ must be adjacent to at least $\delta(G)$ other members of $S$, it must be that $|S| \geq \delta(G) + 1$. By transitivity, $|S| \geq (p-1)/2 + 1 = (p+1)/2$. Since $S \subset V$, it must be true that $|V-S| = |V| - |S| \leq p - (p+1)/2 = (p-1)/2$

However, the set $|V-S|$ must have the same properties that $S$ had, namely that $\forall x \in V-S$, $x$ is adjacent to at least $\delta(G)$ other members of $V-S$. So, just as it was for $S$, $|V-S| \geq (p+1)/2$.

So we have that $|V - S| \leq (p-1)/2$ and $|V-S| \geq (p+1)/2$, a contradiction.
Conclude by reductio ad absurdum that $G$ must be connected.

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: @user454210: Check out Dirac's theorem which gives you a Hamilton cycle. Then think about what you have to do to get a Hamilton path - which is exactly your problem, that is, $G$ is connected because it has a Hamilton path via $\delta(G) \geq (|V|-1/)2$.

Comment: More generally, if $G$ is a simple graph on $n$ vertices such that there exists a positive integer $k$ for which $$\deg(u)+\deg(v)\geq n-k$$ holds for any two non-adjacent vertices of $G$, then $G$ has at most $k$ connected components.